# Remote Machine unreachable while trying to ping through ansible

Tags: ansible, ping

This is my hosts file :

```
[openstack]
ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I am trying to ping it using the following command :

```
ansible openstack -u redhat -m ping -vvvv
```

I got the following response :

```
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/ansible/modules/core/system/ping.py
<ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: redhat
<ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/home/centos/AnsibleKeyPair.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=redhat -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/centos/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480529571.83-128837972481874 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1480529571.83-128837972481874="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480529571.83-128837972481874 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

**NOTE :** I am able to connect to centos machines properly. But, I can't ping Ubuntu and Redhat machines. My controller machine is Centos. What might the problem be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root error while trying to ping remote server using Ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888769/root-error-while-trying-to-ping-remote-server-using-ansible)

Comment: Yaa....both are same. I have edited it many times. So, I have posted it perfectly this time

Answer (score 1):

I solved it finally by using the following command :

```
ansible openstack -u ec2-user -m ping
```

I have been typing **-u redhat** but AWS has already given a name to it automatically **ec2-user**

Answer (score 0):

"ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None" - this means that it is trying to ssh this host using a blank username which will not work.

Two solutions:

1. Edit the hosts file to include ansible_user=ubuntu (or whatever user your flavor uses, i.e. ec2-user for amazon linux)

   [openstack]
   ec2-54-204-230-203.compute-1.amazonaws.com **ansibler_user=ubuntu**
2. Just call it with the -u ubuntu when calling the playbook (or again whatever your flavor uses).

   ansible openstack **-u ubuntu** -m ping -vvvv

Hope this helps!

**--Edit--**
(this is what helped me do it)

1.) Add your ssh key to the ~/.ssh directory

```
touch ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

2.) Enter ssh-agent bash mode

```
ssh-agent bash
```

3.) Ehange its permissionschmod

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

4.) Make a path for ansible to use the permission

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

Comment: I have tried what u said me to do. I got the response and I updated it in the question. Please check it out.

Comment: Ansible is having a hard time with your keys. The best solution I have found for this is to use the ssh-add command to add the ssh key. You should get a Identity added: blah blah blah response if you do the command correctly.

Comment: ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey.pem

Comment: sorry. I keep forgetting that enter submits it.

Comment: The first command you should use is ssh-agent bash and then use ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey.pem command or whatever your key's name is. This makes it so that ansible can access the key very easily.

Comment: I edited my answer above to include what I wrote in the comments

Comment: Thank you...i will try doing so

Comment: Two weeks back, it worked properly. Today, suddenly it started throwing errors. I have changed nothing. And, that too only for redhat and ubuntu machines. It is working properly for centos machines

Comment: Type this command: ssh-keygen -f "~/.ssh/known_hosts" -R  ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com. This has helped me before.

Comment: Another thing is to check if you can actually ssh it yourself.

Comment: Error : No such file or directly.

Comment: Yaa.i could ssh into it. When I type ssh -i AnsibleKeyPair.pem ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com, I get the following error :
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). But when I type ssh -i AnsibleKeyPair.pem ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com, it worked properly

Comment: Ok. Type nano ~/.ssh/mykey.pem  and paste your key in. Type ssh-agent bash, type chmod 600 ~/.ssh/mykey.pem, type ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey.pem. It is important that you actually have your key file with your key and that you added with ssh-add like above. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In your command line, use argument `-k` to ask ssh passwork:

```
ansible openstack -u redhat -m ping -k
```

Comment: I t is asking for an ssh password. But, I have no ssh password. How to set it?

Comment: Ansible use ssh, then what happens when you use command `ssh redhat@ec2-54-152-162-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com` ?